# Python - Subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to call a subclass, for example, class1.class2.function, just like subdomains, shop.domain.com i tried this method

```py
class A:
    class B:
        def ping():
            print("Hi")
a = A()
b = a.B()
```

but it didn't work.
i also tried

```py
class A:
    def ping():
        print("Class A")

class B(A):
    def pingB():
        print("Class B")
```

but also didn't work

Comment: Can you describe what doesn't work?

Comment: @AryanMishra both of the method dosent work, i tried the first method and it raised `<function Class1.Class2.function at 0x0000021E8DAACCA0>`

Comment: Python subclasses are not intended to function like the domain name hierarchy. Also, these aren't subclasses - they're nested classes, which are rarely needed and have some awkward scope quirks.

Comment: @RaphielHS you missed putting self parameter in the methods

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? There are very few problems that nested classes solve.

Comment: Actually, your second snippet makes a subclass. It's not clear what your real goal here is, beneath the terminological confusion. Is the "just like subdomains" thing a guess at how subclasses work, or is your goal to make an interface that works like that? What do these classes represent?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica im planning to make a API for Python support, i know a good API but only works for NodeJS, so i saw one of the functions like `a.b.function`

Comment: To be clear, in your first example, B is not a subclass of A. It just happens to be defined in A's class namespace  but it wouldn't inherit anything from A.

Comment: @RaphielHS: That sounds like a job for either instance attributes or packages and submodules. It doesn't sound like a job for nested classes.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I had to yell because the discussion was becoming a forum in itself. I'm So sorry :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the `self` argument-

IN FIRST CASE:

```py
class A:
    class B:
        def ping(self):
            print("Hi")
a = A()
b = a.B()
b.ping()
```

IN SECOND CASE:

```py
class A:
    def ping():
        print("Class A")

class B(A):
    def pingB(self):
        print("Class B")

b = B()
b.pingB()
```

Hope so this information is useful to you!
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You still need to call the function within the `B` class when initializing `b` as the subclass `B`.  Also, functions within a class need the `self` parameter.

```py
class A:

    class B:

        def ping(self):
            print("Hi")

a = A()  # Initializing variable <a> as new object to class <A>

b = a.B()  # Initializing variable <b> as new object to class <B> (Subclass of a)

b.ping()  # Calling function <ping> which should print the string "Hi"
```